# getElementsByName in restartless (bootstrapped) extension for firefox mobile

Tags: javascript, android, firefox-addon, getelementsbytagname, firefox-addon-restartless

I'm new in extensions development with Firefox in general, and in the mobile version in specific, and I'm facing this problem that's making me insane.

I need to extract  elements with a certain tag name, example `<iframe>` or `<p>` or `<script>`. Naturally I thought about using `getElementsByTagName()`, but it doesn't work for me. Besides, I don't know where exactly I should  put it, since when I link it to a function in a button in a doorhanger, it doesn't work. If I change to the startup function it displays the alert window, but with an empty result (null).

I'm really stuck and i need your help guys. Here the code lines I'm using for that:

```
doc=getBrowser().selectedTab.linkedBrowser.contentDocument;
frames=doc.getElementsByTagName("script");
```

I'm just displaying the length of the array of the extracted elements in an alert window and in a toast, when I press a button in a doorhanger:

```
label: "JavaScript",// the button label in the doorhanger
callback: function() { 
    Services.prompt.alert(null,"the iframes ","Frames Tag shown "+frames.length);// the alert window
    aWindow.NativeWindow.toast.show("Frames Tag shown "+frames.length, "long");//the toast
}
```

Comment: Please add the snippet how you use `frames`.

Comment: I'm just displaying the length of the array of the extracted elements in an alert window, when I press a button in a doorhanger:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well thanks all for your help, I found the solution: this code is binded to the menu button showing the doorhanger:

```
    init();// initialization of the vriables otherwise it won't work
    var tab = window.BrowserApp.selectedTab;
    doc = tab.window.document;// getting the DOM 
    iframes=doc.getElementsByTagName("iframe");// the the iframes
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few differences between desktop and mobile extensions. To begin with, the latter doesn't offer a global getBrowser() or gBrowser. Instead, you have to use the [BrowserApp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Mobile/API/BrowserApp).

Comment: I already tried that,tab = BrowserApp.selectedTab but I don't know how to acces to the DOM of the Tab to get the elements.

Comment: The BrowserApp page has a link to the Tab object page.

Comment: I tried this, but still not working. Are they any ideas or suggestions :var ios = Components
  .classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
doc = BrowserApp.selectedTab.window.document;
frames=doc.getElementsByTagName("script");